# IsAsync is throwing "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a property that takes a long time to load (it creates a thumbnail). When I use the IsAsync binding property it throws the error "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this." How can I fix this?

Comment: This question should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329978/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this

Comment: This may also shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183622/the-calling-thread-must-be-sta-because-many-ui-components-require-this-in-wpf

Comment: Not really. They don't mention the IsAsync property that I'm using. In those threads they're doing the threading manually. Here it's WPF the one doing it.

Comment: Can you show us the logic behind the property you're binding to?  If you set `IsAsync=true` then you need your code to support this. It's going to throw that operation into a background worker and if any of your code modifies elements that operate on the UI thread, then you're going to have issues.